# Bootstrap tag-inputs sending POST with spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working in a system I did not developed made in Django using JQuery and Bootstrap.

I have this tag-inputs:

```
<div id="roles" class="tab-pane"><!-- ROLES -->

            <input id="roles_tag" type="text" value="{{ roles }}" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Add role" />
```

with this javascript:

```
$("#roles_tag").change(function(){
                roles = ($(this).tagsinput('items'));
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "{% url manage_roles %}",
                    data: {
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                        'roles_list': roles
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                });
            });
```

But for a reason I don't know sometimes with send POSTS with a space in the beginning of some tags.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6QfO.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW7sC.png)

What can be causing it? Sorry for any problems, this is my first post here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you try taking data using form control

```
<div id="roledata" class="form-group">
    <label for="last_name" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Roles</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="roles" placeholder="add role">
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var roled = {}

$.each($('#roledata').find('.form-control'), function(){
    var field = this.id,
        value = $(this).val()
        data[field] = value
})

data={
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
    'role' : roled
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",

})
```